# Using the URLconf defined in first_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, url

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't found an answer that solves my situation.

I'm looking at the Django tutorial, and I've set up the first URLs exactly as the tutorial has it, word for word, but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000, it gives me this error:

Using the URLconf defined in first_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='index']
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

I'm using Django 2.2.5 and Python 3.8.

Here is the code I have in relevant url and view files:

In mysite views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World!")
```

In mysite urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In mysite setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]
```

What's going on? Why am I getting 404s?

Comment: That looks like you're using old-style, Django 1, URL patterns, when this was changed (simplified) in Django 2. I guess the tutorial you're following is an old one. Try `path('/',views.index,name='index')` instead

Comment: Thanks sir,
for your valuable comment I got my answer also you are right that was udmy 2017 tutorial but now I am using all update 2020. pray for me

Answer (score 3):

I think you either just need to use blank ' ' as the path for index

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Thanks sir,
for your valuable comment, I got my answer that was udmy 2017 tutorial but now I am using all updates 2020 & you are a genius, sir. pray for me

Answer (score 1):

In Django 2.x.x, `path()` does not accept regular expressions. If you want to use regular expressions then you can use `re_path()` function like

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

or simply use `path()` as suggested by @Antimada. The best practice is to use `path()` or at least avoid mixing both i.e. `path()` and `re_path()`.

Comment: Thanks,  re_path(r'^$',views.index,name='index'), this line saved my life.